# SDK Freezes when idle for 2 min

Tags: bug-reporting

When I let the SDK sit open for about 2 minutes it starts freezing and I can't do any editing to the source unless I expand or minimize the app. I'm not sure on how to fix this. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.